# Swift error: '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm trying to convert the following Objective-C code ([source](http://www.taffysoft.com/pages/20120202-01.html)) from this

```
-(CGRect) dimensionsForAttributedString: (NSAttributedString *) asp {

    CGFloat ascent = 0, descent = 0, width = 0;
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString( (CFAttributedStringRef) asp);

    width = CTLineGetTypographicBounds( line, &ascent, &descent, NULL );

    // ...
}
```

into Swift:

```
func dimensionsForAttributedString(asp: NSAttributedString) -> CGRect {

    let ascent: CGFloat = 0
    let descent: CGFloat = 0
    var width: CGFloat = 0
    let line: CTLineRef = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(asp)

    width = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, nil)

    // ...
}
```

But I am getting the error with `&ascent` in this line:

```
width = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, nil)
```

> '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

Xcode suggests that I fix it by deleting `&`. When I do that, though, I get the error

> Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

The [Interacting with C APIs documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) uses the `&` syntax, so I don't see what the problem is. How do I fix this error?

Comment: The `CTLineGetTypographicBounds` function expects an `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>`, so for example with [withUnsafeMutablePointer](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/func/withUnsafeMutablePointer/) you should create an `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>`, and use that as an input parameter.

Comment: My problem was that I hadn't declared them as variables with the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ascent` and `descent` must be *variables* in order to be passed
as in-out arguments with `&`:

```
var ascent: CGFloat = 0
var descent: CGFloat = 0
let line: CTLineRef = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(asp)
let width = CGFloat(CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, nil))
```

On return from `CTLineGetTypographicBounds()`, these variables will be set to the
ascent and descent of the line. Note also that this function returns
a `Double`, so you'll want to convert that to `CGFloat`.